# I can't get correct max(len(fieldname)) of CSV file using Linq, SQL or MaxLength

Tags: vb.net, linq, csv, ado.net, odbc

I am trying to import a csv file and I need to get the maximum field length so I know how large to make my varchar field in the new table.

I have a small table with the longest text value of 315. Here is a logical description of what is happening:

```
If Len(Field) > 255 And RowNumOf315Record > 25 Then FieldLen = 255
If Len(Field) > 255 And RowNumOf315Record <= 25 Then FieldLen = 315
```

If we nuke all records with the field length > 255 then the correct length is always returned.

I tried Linq:

```
Table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Aggregate(0, Function(current, dRow) Math.Max(current, dRow("STAFF_ID_LAST_UPDT").ToString.Length))
```

I tried a direct query with ADODB:

```
    Dim rsLength As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connX As New ADODB.Connection

    connX.Open("Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=d:\EnvironProcessing\Q2_2016\MN\ust\;Extensions=csv,tab,txt;")
    rsLength.Open("select max(len([STAFF_ID_LAST_UPDT])) as l from [ff_other_liable_leaksites.txt]", connX)
    rsLength.MoveFirst()
    FieldLength = rsLength.Fields("l").Value
    rsLength.Close()
```

I tried using Column.MaxLength:

```
    SourceAdapter.Fill(Table)
    SourceAdapter.FillSchema(Table, SchemaType.Source)
    FieldLength3 = Int(Table.Columns(x).MaxLength / 2)
```

I know that ODBC determines the field type by looking at only the first 25 or so records so I get why FillSchema would fail. But when I am querying the entire table directly or with Linq with an aggregate function, it should actually read the entire table, right?

If I do a Sum or an Avg aggregate it reads the entire dataset.

Comment: what are the actual results of all solutions you tried?

Comment: `.Length`. Please.

Comment: `Dim maxL = dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(s) s.Item(1).ToString.Length).OrderByDescending(Function(w) w).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Plutonix, Same result as the others - returns 255 if the record with the longer value is beyond row 25 and returns 315 if before or at row 25.

Comment: @Visual Vincent. .Length property of what object?

Comment: Thats apparently a limitation of the Text Driver.  Even if I use a Schema and specify 500 char length, it reports 255 *when read via the Text Driver*.  Use CSVHelper or just read the lines to get all the data.

Comment: Instead of the outdated `Len()` function, call `Field.Length`.

Comment: @Visual Vincent. Yes, I do that in code, but plain old SQL is not object oriented like that - you still need to use a function.