# OdbcDataAdapter.Fill never times out

Tags: vb.net, dataadapter

My Fill never times out - and I mean it will run for 15+ minutes on this one table. Here is the code:

```
    Dim ConnectSource As New OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=d:\EnvironProcessing\Q2_2016\OR\brown\;Extensions=csv,tab,txt;")
    Dim SourceAdapter As New OdbcDataAdapter
    Dim dtSource As New Data.DataTable("Source")

    SourceAdapter.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand("Select * from [" & SourceTable & "]", ConnectSource)
    SourceAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
    SourceAdapter.FillSchema(dtSource, SchemaType.Source)
    Try
        SourceAdapter.Fill(dtSource)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I was originally using the default values, so I tried adding my own timeout value. No joy.

Is this yet another problem with the Text driver? Or is there something else I should be doing here.

Comment: How many rows are there?

Comment: About 29,000 rows at 15MB. I just encountered another text file doing the same thing and it only has 841 rows at 218KB. So file size does not appear to be the problem. Both files have fields longer than 255 characters. Microsoft's Text driver exhibits strange and inconsistent behavior around large text fields.

Comment: [I know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759170/i-cant-get-correct-maxlenfieldname-of-csv-file-using-linq-sql-or-maxlength#comment61140687_36759170).  As before, I would look at CSVHelper - let it parse the data and convert to a List(Of T) in very short order.

Comment: I looked at CSV Helper, but it did not seem to do what I needed which was to get an accurate schema of the text file. I am importing into PostgreSQL and it has a very fast text file importer command, but I need to create the table first. I got that nut cracked, until this non-error.